# Recursion function - need some help in writing this function

Tags: c

Write a recursive function 
int mod_rec(int a, int b)
that take a and b parameters , returns the remainder of a divided by b.

You are not allowed to use division operator(/) , modulus operator(%) and loops in this function. As examples , function calls mod_rec (7,3) and mod_rec(3,5) should 1 and 3 respectively.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the value of `INT_MAX` on your platform? And is `mod_rec(2000000001, 2)` supposed to return using a reasonable amount of time and memory?

Comment: Since the parameters and output are declared as int, does the function need to handle negative numbers?

Answer (score 0):

For unsigned integers the function can look like

```
unsigned int mod_rec( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    if ( a == 0 ) return 0;
    else return a >= b ? mod_rec( a - b, b ) : a;
}
```

Take into account that operation % is umdefined when the right operand is zero. Nevertheless you can add check whether b is equal to 0 and in this case return 0. For example

```
unsigned int mod_rec( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    if ( a == 0 || b == 0 ) return 0;
    else return a >= b ? mod_rec( a - b, b ) : a;
}
```

EDIT: It seems the correct function definition will look like:)

```
unsigned int mod_rec( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    if ( b == 0 ) return 0;
    else return a >= b ? mod_rec( a - b, b ) : a;
}
```

Comment: Dont you mean `if (b == 0) return 0;` Even those a/0 isnt valid, it shouldnt stack overflow.

Comment: @Unn As far as I know this operation is undefined for b = 0.

Comment: @Unn  Of course you may realize the function including the check b == 0

Comment: If it's undefined for `b == 0`, you can leave the `if (!a)` check out.

Comment: @EOF No, this check is necessary.

Comment: If `b != 0`, `a >= b` will always be false for `a == 0`, so you're already returning `a` (== 0) in that case.

Comment: Note that the original post shows signed integers, not unsigned. The function will have to handle the case where a and b have opposite signs or both are negative.